# PNaCl supported on chromecast?

Tags: chromecast, google-nativeclient

Is Portable Native Client (PNaCl) supported on Chromecast ? i.e., Will a Chromecast receiver be able to load, translate & execute a pexe module?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not supported on Chromecast.

Comment: I have a PNaCl module which does TCP Socket operations & I intended to use the same on Chromecast receiver. Since PNaCl support is not available, is there an option to perform TCP Socket operations (Socket connect, bind, read, write, close etc..) ? I glanced through Receiver API documentation, but it is not evident  - Thanks

Comment: No, outside of WebSocket, you cannot do anything of that sort.